# How to set Cross Origin with spring mvc annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set Origin parameter in my header, but when I use firebug to analyse my http request, I don't find Origin.

Comment: how did you try to add the header?

Comment: @RequestHeader(value = "Origin", defaultValue = "", required = false) final String origin,

Comment: I don't know what that is doing, but I am pretty sure that is not how you set a header.  You want to use the `HttpServletResponse` and set any headers BEFORE you send any output via the `addHeader(String,String)` method.  I am pretty sure what you have there is how you read in a header from the request into the hander method (or at least one way).

Comment: I'm begginer, and i dont knew how can i do it,